# How to compute the standard error of measurement (SEM) from a reliability estimate?

Tags: spss, reliability

SPSS returns lower and upper bounds for Reliability. While calculating the Standard Error of Measurement, should we use the Lower and Upper bounds or continue using the Reliability estimate.

I am using the formula :

$$\text{SEM}\% =\left(\text{SD}\times\sqrt{1-R_1} \times 1/\text{mean}\right) × 100$$

where SD is the standard deviation, $R_1$ is the intraclass correlation for a single measure (one-way ICC).

Comment: You seem to be calculating the [coefficient of variation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_variation) of the measurement, not the standard deviation or standard error.

Comment: @GaBorgulya Usually, [SEM](http://www.ncme.org/pubs/items/16.pdf) is computed in a different way; contrary to SD or SE, it is supposed to account for scores reliability, specific to the measurement instrument.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the point estimate of the reliability, not the lower bound or whatsoever. I guess by lb/up you mean the 95% CI for the ICC (I don't have SPSS, so I cannot check myself)? It's unfortunate that we also talk of Cronbach's alpha as a "lower bound for reliability" since this might have confused you.

It should be noted that this formula is not restricted to the use of an estimate of ICC; in fact, you can plug in any "valid" measure of reliability (most of the times, it is Cronbach's alpha that is being used). Apart from the NCME tutorial that I linked to in my comment, you might be interested in this recent article:

> Tighe et al. [The standard error of
>   measurement is a more appropriate
>   measure of quality for postgraduate
>   medical assessments than is
>   reliability: an analysis of MRCP(UK)
>   examinations](http://www.biomedcentral.com/1472-6920/10/40). *BMC Medical
>   Education* 2010, 10:40

Although it might seem to barely address your question at first sight, it has some additional material showing how to compute SEM (here with Cronbach's $\alpha$, but it is straightforward to adapt it with ICC); and, anyway, it's always interesting to look around to see how people use SEM.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 ways to calculate SEM. Also it is important if you want to have SEM agreement or SEM consistency. I will show you the SEM calculaton from reliability.

First you should have ICC (intra-class correlation) and the SD (standard Deviation). Then you calculate SEM as follows:
$$
SEM= SD*(\sqrt{1-ICC})
$$

Comment: Welcome to the site, @amin. I took the liberty of editing your post to clean it up slightly & display the formula with $\LaTeX$. Please make sure everything still says what you want.

Comment: Moved the "1-" inside the square root which I believe is the correct relationship